# Doubt in passing in the demonstration of Carathéodory's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

someone can help with the passage marked in red. I've tried in many ways using the definition, but to no avail. This theorem is found in Bartle's book The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue measure on page 142. Definition 13.3 that is needed at this beginning of the demonstration and the condition of Carathéodory $m^*(A)= m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A \cap E^c)$.

Comment: Applying the basic properties of sets should help. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Properties. It seems to me you just need to show that $(E\cap F)^C=F^C$ and similar for the second term's argument.

Comment: Thank you, it was just a silly detail!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the De Morgan's Laws.